# How to get the datas from constructor passed values in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have passed the datas in constructor but how to get the datas in another class?

```
class EmployeeConst(var name:String , var age:String) {
    var profession:String ="Not mentioned"

    constructor(name:String, age: String, profession:String):this(name,age){
        this.profession = profession
    }
        fun getDetails() {
            Log.i("",""+"Employee details is $name whose profession is $profession and age is $age")
        }

}

 class FragmentDashboard : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
             var person= EmployeeConst("name","sdf","test")
            Log.i("Testings",""+person.getDetails()) //here testings is not printing correctly.

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
        }
```

Here in log, I am not getting the passed datas

I/Testings: kotlin.Unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getDetails()` is a void function, ie does not return anything. When you call this method as

```
Log.i("Testings",""+person.getDetails())
```

you're expecting that the method will return a string. There are two solutions:

You change the `Log` in the `FragmentDashboard` class:

```
Log.i("Testings")
person.getDetails()
```

You change the return value of the method `getDetails()`.

```
fun getDetails(): String {
    return "Employee details is $name whose profession is $profession and age is $age"
}
```

Using the second method you can call the method as you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your constructor passed values are not the problem. Your problem is getDetails does not return anything, or in kotlin, it is a Unit.

Here are the improvements that i have created: first, remove overloaded constructor and used a default value for profession. This approach works the same as overloaded method, only, that this has shorter lines. Next, i have fixed your getDetails function to return a string. the equal sign, to put simply, is a shorthand of "return this ->", where in the syntax is

```
fun methodNAme() return this -> something
```

```
class EmployeeConst(
    var name:String,
    var age:String,
    var profession:String = "Not mentioned"
) {
    fun getDetails() =
        "Employee details is $name whose profession is $profession and age is $age"
}

class FragmentDashboard : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        var person= EmployeeConst("name","sdf","test")
        Log.i("Testings",""+person.getDetails()) //here testings is not printing correctly.

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's logging correctly as `getDetails()` is a `Unit` function.

Either log it properly within `getDetails()`:

```
fun getDetails(): Unit {
    Log.i("Testings", "Employee details is $name whose profession is $profession and age is $age")
}
```

Or return the string from `getDetails()`:

```
fun getDetails(): String {
    return "Employee details is $name whose profession is $profession and age is $age"
}
```